# ColorPicker has a bug in XCode 15 beta 8

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

ColorPicker has a bug in XCode 15 beta 8.

There is an issue where ColorPicker pop-up window layout is pushed to the left.

You cannot even select a color in the ColorPicker pop-up window where the problem occurred.

After checking, it does not occur on most iPads and iPhones.

For iPhone SE2 and SE3, problems occur with both the device and the simulator.

XCode 15.0 beta 8 (15A5229m)

iOS 17.0 (21A5326a)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPAs3.png)

Comment: Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).